# COLDFUSION How do I store text file into session? FileNotFoundException

Tags: file, session, exception, coldfusion

I'm still new to ColdFusion and having some issues in uploading cffile into session and reading from another page. Basically, my main objective is to upload text document correctly to the session and lastly, display it on another cfm page.

Form.cfm:

```
<cfif not structKeyExists(session.checkout, "input")>
    <cfset session.checkout.input = {textname="", textemail="", docattach=""}>
</cfif>

<cfparam name="form.textname" default="#session.checkout.input.textname#">
<cfparam name="form.textemail" default="#session.checkout.input.textemail#">
<cfparam name="form.docattach" default="#session.checkout.input.docattach#">

<cfif structKeyExists(form, "Submit")>
    <cfset form.textname = trim(htmlEditFormat(form.textname))>
    <cfset form.textemail = trim(htmlEditFormat(form.textemail))>
    <cffile action="upload" fileField="docattach" destination="#session.checkout.input.docattach#" nameConflict="overwrite">
    <cfset session.checkout.input = {textname=form.textname, textemail=form.textemail, docattach=<--How do I store cffile upload result here?-->}>

    <cflocation url="formcomplete.cfm" addToken="false">
</cfif>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

FormComplete.cfm

```
<cfif not structKeyExists(session, "checkout")>
    <cflocation url="form.cfm" addToken="false">
</cfif>

<cffile action="read" file="#session.checkout.input.docattach#" variable="attachment">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <cfoutput>
        Name: #session.checkout.input.textname#</br>
        Email: #session.checkout.input.textemail#</br>
        Business Rationale: #attachment#    </br>
    </cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

So how exactly can I put it into the session? Another question would be to display the result of images or documents. What are the commands I can use?

Comment: Why do you think you need to put it into the session scope at all?

Comment: @DanBracuk So is there any alternative way you can suggest? Examples?

Comment: I suggest simplicity.  Also, one step at a time.  Submit your form to a page that first, uploads the file.  What you do with it after depends on it's type, but let's say it's an image.  You can display that with an html anchor tag.  If it's another file type, you may want to look at the cfheader and cfcontent tags.

Comment: @DanBracuk I may sound stupid. but.. Where do I upload to? A local directory?

Comment: You upload to the place of specified in the destination attribute of your cffile tag.  The code in your question specifies this:  destination="#session.checkout.input.docattach#"  Hopefully that variable represents a spot on your server.  Speaking of keeping things simple, that's a pretty complicated variable name.  You might be doing unnecessary work somewhere.

Comment: This question could be improved by actually including the full exception/stack trace you received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destination needs to be an actual file path on your server's hard drive (or perhaps RAM drive).  it appears the value of session.checkout.input.docattach is currently an empty string instead of a path.  Once you've uploaded the file, there will be a cffile variable that contains information about the path to the newly-uploaded file and you can then read it in using fileRead() and place the contents into a variable at your discretion.

Check out the docs for cfile action=upload
https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87505342

Also, don't upload the files into a web-accessible directory as that could create a security exploit.

Comment: Will it be better if I just use GetTempDirectory() for all destination?

Comment: That would be a fine solution.  In fact, I believe the docs say that the CF temp directory is used by default so you would just need to get the file name back from the cffile struct and then build the path via getTempDirectory() plus the uploaded file name.  Also, I should have mentioned this earlier, but make sure you can trust the contents of the file or escape it for HTML since your outputting it in the page and it could contain malicious content just as JavaScript exploits or XSS attacks.